# Encoding strings into HTML in Java

Tags: java, html, string, encoding

I need to encode a Java String to display properly as part of an HTML document, e.g. all new lines or tab characters. So I have e.g. `"one\ntwo"`, and I want to get something like `"one<br>two"`. Do you know any library that would do it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using preformat tag `<pre>`

Comment: your answer is not related to question as it not convert line breaks to br. pre tag is used normally to show code as it preserves spaces and line breaks.

Comment: Its not exactly what I asked about, but does the job well enough!

Answer (score 2):

Spring Framework's [`HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(String)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html#htmlEscape(java.lang.String)) method should do the trick:

> Turn special characters into HTML
>   character references. Handles complete
>   character set defined in HTML 4.01
>   recommendation.

Comment: -1 This just converts characters with a code point > 128, not unprintable characters.

Comment: True, but in reality it's fairly unlikely that a string would contain unprintable characters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a library for those simple cases. A simple loop over `string.replaceAll()` should do the trick.

If you are looking for more fancy conversions (such as done here on SO or in a wiki) you can check out the [Java Wikipedia API](http://www.matheclipse.org/en/Java_Wikipedia_API). Code example [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/source/browse/trunk/info.bliki.wiki.test/bliki-test/src/main/java/info/bliki/api/HTMLCreatorTest.java). Although I guess it may be a bit overkill for your needs.